# How to provide cache level security in Apache Ignite?

Tags: security, caching, ignite

I need to restrict one of my Ignite Cache with user level access permissions, couldn't find the reference for the same. any assistance on this is very much  helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Apache ignite provides only the possibility of authentification with password out of the box. It described here:

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/advanced-security

In case if you require for specific security that could grant some access permissions then you can implement the GridSecurityProcessor interface as part of a custom plugin or choose to use a 3rd party implementation (e.g. Gridgain).

Comment: Thanks @Andrei for quick response, can you provide detail reference on how to implement GridSecurityProcessor approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no some official example. But you can try to investigate next example - http://smartkey.co.uk/development/securing-an-apache-ignite-cluster/

Comment: @Sandy, here is the documentation on how to create a plugin: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/plugins

Comment: @AndreiAleksandrov That link is bad, and I can't find an equivalent of it.

Comment: @devinbost probably this one can be equivalent - https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster

Answer (score 0):

Apache Ignite does not provide these kinds of security capabilities with its open-source version. As mentioned by **@Andrei**, you can either implement it on your own or use commercial Gridgain distribution.

Here, you can find steps to implement a custom plugin.

You would need to implement **GridSecurityProcessor** which would be used to authenticate the joining node using **authenticate()** and cache level access permissions can be managed using **authorize()** API.

This blog has more details and custom security plugin source code.

https://www.bugdbug.com/post/how-to-secure-apache-ignite-cluster